# change html <tr> color of last updated row with php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I get assignment where I need to change color of HTML  tag with PHP when is updated in MySQL database. I need some hints?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
& [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions. Can we see the code you already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with these steps:
first you must get the last id with this script:

```
$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

then you can set the color in tr by this code:

```
<?php $data_id = //the id of your data in table ?>
<table>
<tr <?php echo $data_id==$last_id?"style='color:green;'":"" ?>>
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Insert a column to save record modified date "Modified_Date"

You can get last updated date by using below query

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name tb1
WHERE tb1.Modified_Date = (SELECT MAX(tb2.Modified_Date)
FROM table_name tb2
WHERE tb2.primary_key = tb1.primary_key)
```